# Cron Jobs built using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Our team is building cron jobs using node.js to sync up address records from DB2 database into elastic search ,they are feeling node.js is not supported for these high intensity cron jobs which need to sync up nearly 21 million records from DB2 into elastic search ,they are frequently facing some high memory issues and not able to resolve them ,these memory issues lead to termination of the cron jobs without the syncup not happening properly ,they feel we could have developed the application using Java,is this true is node.js inferior to java ,cant it be used for developing high performance cron jobs ??,Thank you Guys ,the existing implementation for this application is built in Java and hibernate has been used as an ORM tool ,since we are rebuilding it in node.js i have asked them to use SQLAlchemy which is a python based ORM but still there is a lot of hue and cry about using Java and hibernate,how good is SQL Alchemy against Java hibernate need your ideas

Comment: In my experience Java typically uses 10x the RAM node uses. So for example if node uses 100MB RAM to do something Java would need 1GB.

Comment: On the other hand, Python uses even less. So for example if node uses 100MB to do something Python would only need around 10MB - 20MB

Comment: What I feel is probably happening is your developers don't know how to write proper javascript code to take advantage of async I/O and parallel batching (without using threads). So the node.js code they are writing is very bad and performs badly. In which case as a product manager I'd just let my developers use a language they are more familiar with so they know how to optimize for issues like this better

Comment: It is also possible that your developers are really bad at DB2 thus don't know how to batch the queries needed and instead makes a single query that returns 21 million rows. Or don't know how to properly index a database and the DB2 queries end up being slow.

Comment: Instead of sticking into a programming language, you should try using logstash(open-source ETL tool by elasticsearch) It consists simple YAML kind of configuration where you need to pass source(DB2) and destination and it would get your job done pretty easily and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Languages typically don't determine performance unless you end up using a ton of "built-in" or so-called standard libraries, which is most often the case.

Java is known to be a memory-hog, so that answers the Java part.

Node.js is definitely better, but if you really need performant code, you will have to go lower - Golang is better, c++ is even better.

With regard to your performance issues, if time and number of queries is not an issue, you should simply avoid grabbing large data sets in one shot. When you query for something large, the entire response would now reside in-memory till you destroy the result. For migrations, it is best to do loop through small pieces of data which will reduce the memory pressure.